# flex 3 togglebuttonbar vertical text label in buttons

Tags: flex3, label, togglebuttonbar

How could i write vertical text on a toggle button bar that is vertically arranged.

Answer (score 0):

@seismael Do you mean vertical as in written sideways up the screen, or letter below each letter?

Comment: i mean written sideways up the screen or down and not normal letters written one below the other